# Hot deployment of JavaEE applications using Maven-Cargo pluin

Tags: java, jboss, cargo, hotdeploy, maven-cargo

I am using maven-cargo plugin for deployment of a very simple JavaEE application.
And I was able to run and deploy to jboss **but the hot deployment of the class files and jsps is not working.**
(By hot deployment I mean when I change my Java classes then the changes should be reflected in the application without the server being getting restarted.)

For understanding cargo, I went through their documentation:

https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven2+plugin.html

and various other So links also :

[maven - Failed to execute cargo:start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061318/maven-failed-to-execute-cargostart)

[Maven2: Cargo plugin hot deployment & Jonas support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394389/maven2-cargo-plugin-hot-deployment-jonas-support)

[Deploy web application using Cargo plugin to remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55891511/deploy-web-application-using-cargo-plugin-to-remote-server)

But none of posts gives an adequate answer to the questions.

I am using following maven goals which I am using to run and deploy my application :
`cargo:deploy`
`cargo:run`

Following the configuration done in pom.xml :

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
      <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
      <configuration>
        <container>
          <containerId>jboss71x</containerId>
          <type>installed</type>
          <home>C:\softwares\jboss\jboss-eap</home>
        </container>
        <configuration>
            <type>existing</type>
          <home>C:\softwares\jboss\jboss-eap\standalone</home>
        </configuration>
        <deployer>
          <type>installed</type>
        </deployer>
        <deployables>
          <deployable>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-demo</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
          </deployable>
        </deployables>
      </configuration>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
          <artifactId>jboss-as-controller-client</artifactId>
          <version>7.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: . (By hot deployment I mean when I change my Java classes then the changes should be reflected in the application without the server being getting restarted.) ==> if you update the application on JBoss deployment directory yes. So you change the code, compile, generate a new app, update on JBoss directory. Hot deployment means you <do not stop the server when deploying>

Comment: @FranciscoMelojunior :for instance when I use eclipse IDE and use the application server from inside of eclipse,the changes are automatically deployed to the server when the project builds again.I explicitly do not compile or generate a new app, it happens automatically.This is not happening when I am using cargo plugin.

Comment: humm, interesting, This is happen when you are <using> or when you are <not> using? add the server.log here pls.